# ¿ Cómo evitar que facebook auto inicié método de compartir sin seleccionarlo previamente?

Tags: java, android, facebook, método

Estoy utilizando el SDK de Facebook. tengo un método para compartir en cada red social disponible en el dispositivo, al momento de enviar abrir el dialogo de compartir predeterminado por el sistema, se auto ejecuta compartir con facebook sin seleccionarlo antes, cosa que no pasa con twitter. ya que al momento de seleccionar twitter va a twitter, facebook se autoselecciona y no me deja escoger otra red social.

Las redes sociales estarán disponibles dependiendo de las aplicaciones que tenga el usuario instaladas.

**fragment.java**

```
public void shareIt(View view){
        Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imagencompartir);
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent,0);
        for(final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
            String packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
            Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
           targetedShareIntent.setClassName(app.activityInfo.packageName, app.activityInfo.name); // add
            if(packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana") ){
            //    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setLinkShare();
               // targetedShareIntent.putExtra(this, MyIntentService.class);
               // targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, titulo.getText().toString());
                setLinkShare();
            } else
            if(packageName.equals("com.twitter.android")){
                targetedShareIntent.setType("application/twitter");
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, titulo.getText().toString().trim() );
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
            } else {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, titulo.getText().toString());
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, titulo.getText().toString());
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, comentariocompartir.getText().toString().trim());
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
            }
            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
        }
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), getActivity().getString(R.string.compartir_con));

        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, RESULT_SHARE);

    }
```

**Metodo compartir en Facebook**

```
public void setLinkShare() {
    ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()

            .setContentTitle(titulo.getText().toString().trim())
            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://scontent-sin6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/13403381_247495578953089_8113745370016563192_o.png"))
            .setContentDescription(comentariocompartir.getText().toString().trim())
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/"))
            .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                    .setHashtag("#app"+" "+ "#facebook")

                    .build())
            .setQuote(titulo.getText().toString().trim())
            .build();

    shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.NATIVE);
}
```

**Dependencia**

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

**imagen**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen se auto selecciona facebook  y las otras opciones disponibles quedan abajo del dialogo de compartir

Comment: sé que podría ser irrelevante, pero la app de facebook no está seleccionada como app por defecto para esa operación?

Comment: no, es decir compruebo los paquetes instalados, y de alli envio compartir un contenido distinto para cada red social instalada en el dispositivo, si hubiera alguna manera de llamar al metodo de facebook con un intent se solucionaria, ya que en las demas no ocurre ese problema porque utlizo intent, pero facebook tiene sus opciones que obligan a usar el sdk